# why use the root to calculate the norm of vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that the norm comes from the Pythagorean theorem: $$a^2+b^2=c^2.$$
So why is the vector length not $c^2$?
Why use root like that $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$?
Thank you.

Comment: Because the length of the segment is the one you measure with the ruler.

Comment: What is the size of the vector $(2,0)$?

Comment: $L=2\:OR\:L^2=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a norm must be *absolutely homogeneous* (or absolutely scalable) that is

$$\|\lambda \vec v\|= \lambda \|\vec v\|$$

According to the physical interpretation of length, we have that the square root preserves the dimension.

---

The main point is that the norm of a vector is defined in such way it is "*comparable*" with the components of the vector. For this reason, in the case of euclidean norm we take the square roots. For the case $(2,0)$, using square root we have that $\|(2,0)+(2,0)\|=4$, which corresponds to the "*natural*" definition of length, otherwise we would obtain $16$.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "square root preserves the dimension"?

Comment: @NFLX According to the comment by André Caldas, the norm for $(2,0)$ without square root would be $4$, from a physical point of view, if $a,b$ are lengths then $a^2+b^2$ are areal quantities and by the square root we obtain a length again which is comparable with $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Why 4?
You can just say that the length squared is equal to 4.

Comment: @NFLX The main point is that the norm of a vector is defined in such way it is "comparable" with the components of the vector. For this reason, in the case of euclidean norm we take the square roots. For the case $(2,0)$, using square root we have that $\|(2,0)+(2,0)\| =4$, which corresponds with the "natural definition of length, otherwise we woild obtain $16$.

Comment: now it's clear thanks.

Comment: @NFLX You are welcome! It was not easy understand the origin of your doubt. I update the answer with that!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be asking this question.

In

$$a^2+b^2=c^2,$$

$a,b$ are the lengths of the sides of the right angle, and I am sure that you don't question that, by thinking that the sides are $a^2$ and $b^2$. So why should wonder that the third side be $c^2$ and not $c$ ???

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves downvotes